# I'm trying to find what effect was used in this image. Looks like CRT overlay but I'd like to see if anyone has a more specific response

Tags: effects

[image: Crt scan looking overlay]

Does anyone have any idea what visual effect this is?

Comment: I don't think this is a deliberate "effect".  It looks to me like a copy of a bad quality laser print, possibly a copy of a copy of a copy, which has then been enlarged causing it to look blurry.

Comment: Several copies of the same cloth photo colorized, scaled and rotated differently, with drop shadows, noisy overlays - a horizontally stretched noise or more likely a fabric pattern, noisy logos, icons and a text blocks. Spred also color a little wider than on the clothes and the number icons. Easy to make the original, impossible to make from scratch an exact replica. Splashing various items together few minutes & saving as low quality jpg gave this https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwwpf.jpg The creator of the ad may have it as a single click effect if he happened to build it as a script or action.

Comment: @user287001 Thanks. What did you use for the stretched noise/pattern? Like a source. Again, thanks, this helped.

Comment: make a new layer, fill it with 50%bright grey, add 120% monochromatic noise, Gaussian Blur 1 px, treshold to 35%, select all white, delete, scale layer content horizontally to 500% to get long fibers, squeeze vertically to 50% to make them thin, duplicate layer and move the copy to have the full image height of fibers. reduce opacity to make it grey against white BG , make also a white version to be used with low opacity only on clothes. Add slightly also on everything non-blurred noise.